# Efficient implementation of multiple return values?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, language-design

Is it possible to implement efficiently (with little to no runtime overhead) functions that return multiple vales / a tuple type?

In a C-like language something like this:

```
int, float f(int a) {
  return a*2 , a / 2;
}
```

Is there a reason why very few statically compiled languages do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be efficient. You may need to spill registers, but it is possible.

GHC for example, implements the ["constructed product return"](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/cpr/index.htm) optimization, that:

> determines when a function can profitably return multiple results in registers. The analysis is based only on a function's definition, and not on its uses (so separate compilation is easily supported) and the results of the analysis can be expressed by a transformation of the function definition alone.

CPR is a huge win for returning small structures (i.e. tuples, tagged unions).

More information:

- [CPR analysis](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1885) in GHC.
- More on [demand analysis.](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/Demand)

Answer (score 3):

The best paper I have read exactly about this topic is [An Eﬃcient Implementation of Multiple Return Values in Scheme (PDF)](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/pubs/mrvs.pdf). Although it is about Scheme programming language, they explain the matter in terms of low machine level stack/registry implementation.

This article actually made me think that many high-level features normally considered inefficient are a solved problem regarding the efficient implementation and just the inertia of the popular languages is in the way.

Answer (score 1):

If your tuple doesn't fit into a single register (32- or 64-bit, depending on your architecture, most likely), then there's going to be actual allocation (most likely on the heap) involved in implementing this.

That said, the reasons why very few languages permit this style is unlikely to be related to performance as much as it is likely related to stylistic concerns in the language (i.e., there are other idiomatic ways to achieve the same thing, such as returning a struct).  Introducing new primitives to the language can be clumsy and introduce inconsistencies.  For example, if tuples become first-class values, can I use them anywhere?  How do I access them?  Do we enforce immutability?  How do I allocate or deallocate them?

Languages with more expressive type systems tend to make it easier to add these kinds of language features in a principled manner, which is why you'll find tuples (and all sorts of other exotic creatures) as first-class values in languages derived from the ML family (amongst others).

Answer (score 0):

In C, just return a `struct` holding the values. Sure, the result won't fit in a register, unlike an `int`, so it will not be as efficient as an `int` return, but it will still be efficient, if the `struct` is a local variable and thus allocated on the stack rather than the heap.